# Caldera Debian installation halt when running preseed

Tags: installation, debian

I am installing Caldera RIP Software (https://www.caldera.com/). Caldera software is shipped with a caldera debian. When install this debian, installation always halt when it is running preseed.

I have tried it on VMware virtual machine、Oracle VirtualBox and an usb harddisk.

Anybody has the same problem? And how can I solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

[Screenshot when installation halt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv62z.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wait 15 min, install success.
^_^(I think it needs to give some tips).